# Quanteda, textmodel_wordfish, "the algorithm did not converge"

Tags: quanteda

I am trying to estimate a wordfish model with the latest version of quanteda (1.3.0) - yet, keep getting the message:

```
Warning message:
In textmodel_wordfish.dfm(speaker_dfm, dir = c(28, 2)) :
Warning: The algorithm did not converge.
```

The dfm is grouped by docvars and currently relatively small at around 700000 elements (I have tried several sizes and kinds of dfms, always the same warning message). A couple of days ago (before the most recent quanteda update) it went smoothly with a much bigger dfm. Any idea how to fix this? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends a lot on the sparseness of the dfm, which is unknown from your question.  This unsupervised model will have a lot of trouble if your dfm is nearly all zeroes.

Steps you can take:

1. Reduce the number of low-frequency features using `dfm_trim()`.
2. Try running the model with `sparse = TRUE`.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply - indeed, I need to check my dfms, sorry for suspecting the recent Quanteda update.